# TinyMCE Line Returns in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer-8, struts, tinymce

When editing text with the tinyMCE editor in Internet Explorer, if I add additional blank lines between paragraphs, the following HTML code is generated by tinyMCE:

```
<p>..</p>..<p>..</p>
```

The setter in my Struts 1 ActionForm reports receiving the following string:

```
<p>Â </p><p>Â </p>
```

This problem does not occur in Firefox, but only with IE 8.

Does anyone have any suggestions about why the tinyMCE editor is not correctly posting line returns with IE 8 and Struts 1?

Comment: As a followup, I found that the problem stems from the fact that my html form has the attribute enctype="multipart/form-data" set. If I remove the multipart enctype, the problem goes away. Unfortunately, my form needs to post multipart data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround: Add server-side code to remove "Â" characters from the input string.